# West Marches campaign for settings other than medieval fantasy

Tags: science-fiction, modern, west-marches

The concept of a West Marches campaign is geared mainly toward fantasy/medieval campaigns, mostly, I think, due to the ease of creating wilderness areas and regions that are suitable to that style of campaign.

I am interested in setting up a West Marches campaign in a modern or future/sci-fi setting. Are there any resources or examples of this style of campaign in one of these more technologically-oriented settings? How would one go about creating such a campaign without resorting to post-apocalypse?